# Does Hazelcast provide an L2 (Second Level) distributed cache for EclipseLink?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, hazelcast

Hazelcast offers an L2 cache for Hibernate as documented in their manual here: http://hazelcast.com/docs/2.1/manual/single_html/#HibernateSecondLevelCache.

My question is if there is the same for EclipseLink? (I'm thinking not but maybe someone knows if there are plans for it, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is no, but [they are open to contributions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hazelcast/p8bajSH5URM) since it's open source.

Comment: [hazelcast forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/hazelcast/p8bajSH5URM)